# Did your still using Laravel's Collective in year 2020?

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

Currently, I had receiving a new project. I am thinking of whether do I need to include the `Laravel's Collective` into the system. For me, my consideration is more on maintenance part cause if I include laravel, new programmer need to spend extra time to understand the package.  Any idea?

Comment: Do you need its functionality?

Comment: Cee, thanks for comment. Would you further elaborate what do you mean by functionality in this scenario? Any example?

Comment: Maybe, I put it in this way, if you have a new project, would you include laravel collective and why?

Comment: No. It's clutter.

Comment: It was in the laravel's core once and it got removed due to existence of components

Comment: Every web developper knows how to write a simple html form. Laravel collective forces people to look at the documentation just to write text inputs. And if you really want to write reusable components, laravel supports that already through blade.

Comment: IGP, yup I agree with you. It make thing complicated. AH.Pooladvand, yes, that is the question that I am asking myself, if it was so good, why would the core team removed it from the core functionality and does not maintain it anymore.

Comment: @IGP There is *some* useful stuff in it still, like the automatic handling of "old" input when a validation exception occurs. It's really a matter of opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use it, I think it has no sense when you can make the same things that it was meant for but without adding it.